# NGINX failed to work while configuring server for subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cloud

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Prior to this prompt, the server was working fine, but when I tried to config the server for subdomain it failed to work with this error.

Also for detailed error ...

```
[ec2-user@ip--------- conf.d]$ systemctl status nginx.service

? nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-07-07 06:03:04 UTC; 4min 17s ago
  Process: 71445 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 71444 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 70298 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy serv>
Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal nginx[71445]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expec>
Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal nginx[71445]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.c>
Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=ex>
Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 07 06:03:04 ip-999.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse pro>
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check configuration errors by using this command :

```sh
nginx -T
```

before launch a catastrophic restart :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error `unexpected end of file`, check the syntax of your NGINX configuration as it is likely that you have a broken file.

The likely candidate is forgetting to close a `}` character.